# How to loop through matrix and count zero-term values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

```
sample collection = 
[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 
['apple', 1, 1, 1, 1], 
['banana', 1, 1, 0, 0], 
['lemon', 1, 0, 2, 1]]
```

In preperation of an tf-idf calculation, I would like to collect every row's amount of 'hits' aka, the amount of times there is not a zero.

I have tried the following but I am stuck:

```
def n_calc(frequency_matrix):
    non_zero_term_frequencies = []
    for list_ in sample_collection:
        for value in list_:
            if value != 0.0:
                non_zero_term_frequencies += 1
            else:
                pass

idf_calc(sample_collection)
```

desired output:

```
non_zero_term_frequencies: [4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Couple of things right off the bat: you probably want to do `non_zero_term_frequencies.append(value)` and the `else: pass` is implicit.

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[sum(1 if val !=0 else 0 for val in row[1:]) for row in sample_collection[1:]]`. The first row and first column of the sample data are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like this:

```
non_zero_term_frequencies = []
for list_ in frequency_matrix[1:]:
    non_zero = len(list_[1:]) \
               - len([x for x in list_ if x == 0])
    non_zero_term_frequencies.append(non_zero)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension, this should work:

```py
counts = [
    sum(1 if value else 0 for value in line[1:]) for line in collection[1:]
]

print(counts)
>>> [4, 2, 3]
```